# Bind hidden inputs to model in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hidden-field

I have following form:

```
<form name="frmInput">

    <input type="hidden" ng-model="record.usersId" value="{{user.userId}}"/>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="record.userNameId" value="{{user.userNameId}}"/>
    <label for="fileNo">AccountId</label>
    <input id="fileNo" ng-model="record.fileNo" required/>
    <label for="madeSad">MadeSad</label>
    <input id="madeSad" ng-model="record.madeSadNo" required/>

    <button ng-disabled="!frmInput.$valid" ng-click="SaveRecord(record)">Accept</button>

</form>
```

I get `record.fileNo` and `record.madeSadNo` in `SaveRecord` function but i don't get `record.usersId` and `record.userNameId` in `SaveRecord` function.

Where am i making mistake?

values of hidden inputs are correct.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Having hidden form fields is not the Angular way. You don't need hidden fields at all, as the all the scope variables (which are not in the form) can be taken as hidden variables.

As for the solution, while submitting the form, just populate the object 'record' with 'user':

```
function SaveRecord(){
  $scope.record.usersId = $scope.user.userId;
  $scope.record.userNameId = $scope.user.userNameId;
  http.post(url, $scope.record);
}
```

As a side note, you do not need to mention your variable while calling the function:

```
<button ng-disabled="!frmInput.$valid" ng-click="saveRecord()">Accept</button>
```

Comment: Yes, finally i did that, with similar approach

Comment: I don't know if that's an accurate statement.. "hidden variables is not angular way".. what if I have an authorization schema, and depending on the user entering the site, the hidden input is what determines that value? I'd rather not do any authorization in my javascript, but let my view handle it.

Answer (score 24):

You can use something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="record.usersId" value="{{user.userId}}" ng-init="record.usersId=user.userId"/>
```

Comment: I like this. Of course using hidden fields is not required, as I could just populate directory from the scope....but when one has a page and all other form variables come from form elements...hidden fields helps keep the code clean and consistent

Comment: ng-init was key, i wouldn't want to populate the fields in my controller/service as that doesn't help for reusability. In my case, I use a submit function in two places, one where all the data is from the form already, so why make the function ugly? :)

Answer (score 2):

Hidden field does not support double binding.

Just use this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{user.userId}}"/> {{user.userId}}
<input type="hidden" name="UserNameId" value="{{user.userNameId}}"/> {{user.userNameId}}
```

Comment: But i want to get `usersId` and `userNameId` as fields of `record` parameter of `SaveRecord(record)`

Comment: your solution does bind to the model